# PHP Session problem

Tags: php, session, xampp

Hi
I'm learning PHP.
Using xampp i'm testing codes, and register_globals is ON.
Just wrote a simple code to test session, but it doesn't work i don't know why !?
Admin with pass 123 logs in correctly but when i click to go to admin area, it returns me to the login page, because the session doesn't seem to be set:

This is the check.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $u = $_POST['tfUser'];
    $p = $_POST['tfPass'];
    if (($u == "admin") && ($p == "123"))
    {
        print ("Okay! Go to Admin area "."<a href='admin.php'>Click Here</a>");
        $_SESSION["testSession"] = $mySession;  
    }
    else
    {
        print ("Nope !");
    }
?>
```

This is the admin.php page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["testSession"]))
    {
        echo "Hello !";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">
        window.location.href="login.php";
        </script>';
        return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: There's no good reason to keep `register_globals` on. Turn it off, even if it is just a learning environment, you don't want to catch any bad habit...

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and turn register_globals off ASAP. It may seem like a useful thing, but it also adds a potential security risk if you're not careful: with register_globals on, any global variable that is used without prior initialization can be injected from the outside, by simple adding a suitable query string parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
<?php
session_start();
    $u = $_POST['tfUser'];
    $p = $_POST['tfPass'];
    if (($u == "admin") && ($p == "123"))
    {
        print ("Okay! Go to Admin area "."<a href='admin.php'>Click Here</a>");
        $_SESSION["testSession"] = $u;  // or something else (string, or any other var which must be having some values) 
    }
    else
    {
        print ("Nope !");
    }
```

You are using `$mysession` which is not initialized, so it will be set to null.

Answer (score 3):

Check that `$mySession` is defined and isn't null. `isset` will return false if the variable is set to `null`

Answer (score 3):

Set your error reporting on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You get a similar error as your mySession var isn't defined.

Notice: Undefined variable: hey in /test.php on line 8

Oh, and as long as you are leaning PHP, get rid of the JavaScript and go with:

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

It will have the same result, even if someone has JavaScript turned off.

Comment: +1 for the note on JS, but always remember to put a `die` or a `return` statement after `header` if you're using it to redirect to another page. This will avoid executing any instruction that comes after. Very useful especially if he's learning, because one tends to think that the `header` instruction immediately redirects the page, which is not true.

Comment: great point on using die(). I often forget to do that myself.